how to inject component to constructor parameter using configuration file
I'm trying to inject constructor parameters using a configuration file, but it seems autofac only supports builtin primitive types, any suggestions? thanks
following is the code
{
  "defaultAssembly": "Demo",
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "demo.AddCalculator",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "demo.ICalculator",
          "key": "add"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "demo.ChainedCalculator",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "demo.ICalculator",
          "key": "chain"
        }
      ],
      "parameters": {
          "target": "add" # should reference to the add Calculator 
      }
    }
  ]
}


Short version: you can't.
You won't be able to - via configuration - do complex parameter specification. Since configuration has to be deserialized from string, any parameter value you specify must be convertible from a string. You could implement type conversion on your object to enable this, but that's probably overkill.
From the docs:

Before diving too deeply into JSON/XML configuration, be sure to read Modules - this explains how to handle more complex scenarios than the basic JSON/XML component registration will allow. Configuration in JSON/XML is not a feature-for-feature replacement for programmatic configuration, so complex scenarios may require a combination of JSON/XML and modules.

Thus, you may need to use modules to enable your configuration needs - set up the registrations in a module, them use config to register the right set of modules for your needs.
It may also be that not everything needs to be in configuration. In your example, the ChainedCalculator has a keyed service requirement. If the only thing you swap out is the keyed service, register ChainedCalculator in code and only register the things that actually change in configuration.
Finally, an observation - the config in the docs shows a lot of options being used (like keyed services) but the vast majority of the time keyed services aren't needed. Trying to tightly control "this instance goes to this service but that instance goes to this other service" may indicate a design problem. You should usually be able to inject by type, which means you wouldn't need to specify the dependency as a parameter. It'd automatically wire up.
